# Honing the .hgignore file using a negative lookahead

Tags: regex, mercurial, hgignore

I've looked at a handful of the other Hg hgignore file questions, but I haven't been able to get my regex to work.

Imagine these files:

```
Projects/search.intrasearch/newUI/override/xslt/foo.xsl
Projects/search.intrasearch/newUI/default/
Projects/search.intrasearch/oldUI/baz/
```

I want to ignore the second two lines, but not the first. So, in Mercurial, I want to **include** files in the newUI/override directory and it's children, but that's it. In the real system, there are a bunch more directories than above, so simply excluding oldUI and default won't work. I need a method of **inclusion**.

This works in a regex tool, but not in Mercurial:

`(?i)Projects/search\.intrasearch/(?!newUI/override).*`

Comment: It looks like that should work, so I would file a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured this out by using a combination of two regex's:

```
(?i)Projects/search.*?/newUI/(?!override).*
(?i)Projects/search[^/]*/(?!newUI).*
```

This seems to successfully exclude anything that's a sibling to newUI and anything that's a sibling to override.

Comment: Actually, I must wait another two days, apparently. Some of us aren't as special as others.