# Weird negative lookahead handling in hgignore

Tags: regex, mercurial, tortoisehg, hgignore, regex-lookarounds

Out of a huge source tree, i want just one subfolder be tracked by Mercurial.

```
specific/component/subfolder
```

In any decent regex tool (Regex Coach, regexpal.com), the following is absolutely sufficient (and understandable)

```
^(?!specific/component/subfolder).+
```

meanwhile .hgignore insists on having

```
^(?!extras).+
^extras/(?!extensions).+
^extras/extensions/(?!sharing).+
```

as soon as i put slash inside the lookahead group, nothing gets through.

Before calling this a bug (perhaps of yet another homegrown regex parser?) i ask the collective inteligence :-)

Credits for indirect clue on what the heck hgignore wants go to

[Honing the .hgignore file using a negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996920/honing-the-hgignore-file-using-a-negative-lookahead)

Answer (score 5):

Just don't use negative lookahead in .hgignore.  Really.  Every time someone suggests it here in Stack Overflow I chime in letting them know that it doesn't work well because it's not an intended feature.  If Mercurial's .hgignore file was supposed to be a whitelist system it would have a real whitelist syntax.  It's a blacklist and should be used as such.

The negative lookahead syntax almost-works precisely because it's not a homegrown regex parser -- it's the one built into python and going out of the way do disable negative lookahead seems like overkill, but maybe was the better choice.

Two solutions better than using the never-going-to-be-satisfying-to-you negative look ahead handling:

- just move the repository one level lower -- down into the folder you actually want to track
- -or- blacklist everything and then 'hg add' the files you want track -- add overrides ignore

Seriously.  This wasn't an intended feature and it's never going to work well but can't be removed for backwards compatibility reasons.

Comment: Well so from the sheer amount of suggestions, an actual whitelist might be an useful feature right? :) In my case, neither of your suggestion is applicable, and it might be a popular situation. Hg is a dev supplement for the master upstream svn. So we need the patches to be compatible - rooted in the same directory. And developers are unreliable in remembering to do manual add everytime they create something. Even worse when it gets created for them by some RAD tool. I for one am thankful that at least such hackish whitelisting works.

Comment: I wasn't in on the decision to make ignores blacklist only, but I do think it was the right one.  It's easy enough to do `hg status --unknown --no-status > .hgignore` to ignore everything that currently exists and isn't added.  Making sure people see everything they're choosing not to protect with a '`?`' in front of it at least once seems in line with the err-on-the-side-of-caution I've observed from Mercurial's ui.

Comment: The link ends up on Bugzilla main page. This one is perhaps more up to date: http://bz.selenic.com/show_bug.cgi?id=712 It looks like the definitive source of informations if anything ever evolves on this front. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, here's Matt's take on it in his own words: This is an ancient and recurring feature request, which I turned down well
before this bug was created. I've written and supported a couple
include/exclude file syntaxes and have decided I would rather say "no, you can't do that" once to 1% of users than "no, you're reading the docs wrong" repeatedly to 20% of users.