# Is there a way to select what I want in hg, not ignore what I don't want

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

I know Hg's ignore is useful, but is there a way that I can specify what files I do care, and just ignore the rest, for instance.

if I have `a.c, a.h, a.o, a.exe, a.err` in the repo, is there a way I can tell Hg, I just want to keep `*.c *.h` and just ignore everything not on the list.

Comment: Seems to be similar to whitelist, like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512058/hgignore-help-ignoring-all-files-but-certain-ones but Ry4an won't be happy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10434978/6309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heh, @vonC is right, I couldn't let this go by.  There isn't a way to turn hgignore into a whitelist instead of a blacklist.  I gather it's that way by design (I certainly didn't design  it).

You have a few options:

1. Add *everything* (`.*`) to your `.hgignore` and then `hg add` file you want to be tracked -- adding always overrides ignoring
2. Just break down and make a proper black list: `hg status --no-status --unknown >> .hgignore` is a great starting point.

The bottom line is accidentally tracking something you didn't want tracked is less dangerous a situation than accidentally forgetting to track something you wished was tracked.  The former creates a little noise in the your repo, while the latter results in potential data loss.

If you really wanted to get fancy you could add '`.*`' to your `.hgignore` and then create a hook like this:

```
[hooks]
precommit.add = hg add $(hg status --unknown --no-status -I '**.c' -I '**.h')
```

which would automatically add any new .c and .h files when you commit.

Comment: is `[hooks]` a plug in for hg?

Comment: btw, what's the difference between `*.c` and `**.c` although this is another question:)

Comment: no, hooks are in-built functionality.  Try `man hgrc` or read chapter 10 of the Mercurial book for an explanation.  **.c includes *.c in all paths.  In brief `*` matches anything except a slash, and `**` matches _anything_.

Comment: It is not working for me. I think the hook should be `pre-commit` with the dash as @Ry4an says in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708929/mercurial-including-precommit-changed-file/11714777#11714777), and the `--unknown` option should be `--ignored` as ignored files are known. So the code could be `pre-commit.add = hg add $(hg status --ignored --no-status -I '**.c' -I '**.h')`