# mercurial: including precommit-changed file

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

On commit to repository I have a hook defined in Mercurial:

```
[hooks]
precommit.exportDB=exportDB.bat
```

This creates/updates a SQL-dump from my database, which should be included in the commit.
BUT: although this works, the Sql is marked as new, but not part of the now commiting changeset.
How can I automatically include it so it gets into the set of changed files?

Hope this makes sense...

Thx
Reinhard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This'll sound crazy, but you can do it in two steps.  First change your `precommit` hook to a `pre-commit` hook -- yup, both exist and they're different.  Without the dash the commit has already started and some lock has been acquired.  With the dash it happens before the commit starts and you can still `hg add` the new file.

On a unix like that total change would be:

```
[hooks]
pre-commit.exportDB=exportDB.sh && hg add resulting.sql
```

presumably there's something similar on Windows, or you could make the `hg add` the last line of the batch file.

P.S. Don't commit generated files. :)

**Update:**

I just tested this and it works as I suggested:

```
ry4an@four:~$ hg init reinhard
ry4an@four:~$ cd reinhard/
ry4an@four:~/reinhard$ vi .hg/hgrc
ry4an@four:~/reinhard$ cat .hg/hgrc 
[hooks]
pre-commit = hg add otherfile
ry4an@four:~/reinhard$ echo text > afile
ry4an@four:~/reinhard$ echo more > otherfile
ry4an@four:~/reinhard$ hg add afile
ry4an@four:~/reinhard$ hg status
A afile
? otherfile
ry4an@four:~/reinhard$ hg commit -m 'message'
ry4an@four:~/reinhard$ hg status --all
C afile
C otherfile
```

Notice that before the commit only 'afile' is added and 'otherfile' is unknown, and after the commit both files are 'C' (meaning "Clean' -- they've been added and committed).

Comment: thx for the tip with pre-commit. I also added 'hg add newfile.sql' at the end of my script. But this only triggers another, successive commit, so it is not inside the first changeset...

Comment: yes this works - but I tried to make a one-click-updateSQLdump-and-commitChanges using TortoiseHG on windows. This is making the problem, as the newly added file did not make it to the Changeset, probably because on clicking Commit the list of files is already there, before the new one is created. THANKS AGAIN for your time and  effort!!